# Hibernate one to many automatically insert id

Tags: java, hibernate

So i have a very basic construction where i have a client and this client could have multiple addresses.

So in hibernate i did something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_clients")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_client")
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fkIdClientAddress", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AddressClient> addressClientList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the other class looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_clients_address")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class AddressClient {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_client_address")
    private Integer id;



    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_client")
    private Client Client;

    @Column
    private Integer fkIdClientAddress;
```

When inserting a client into the database who has 2 addresses it works but the fields fkIdClientAddress  and id_client is are empty in the database. So i have no idea to who the address belong.

How can i fix this? And what is wrong with this construction?

first improvements

Class AddressClient

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_clients_address")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class AddressClient {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_client_address")
    private Integer id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_client")
    private Client client;
```

Class Client

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_clients")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_client")
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AddressClient> addressClientList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is looking better but the field id_client is still null

When i created a for each and save the AddressClients again the id is successful saved.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addclient",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addClient(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user,@RequestBody Client client) {


        //FIND THE ACTIVE USER
        LOGGER.info("SQL: GET PRINCEPAL USER");
        User getuser = userDao.findByEmail(user.getName());



        for (AddressClient addressClient : client.getAddressClientList())
        {
        addressClient.setClient(client);
        }

        clientDao.save(client);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong. First of all, you don't need two different columns (`id_client` and `fkIdClientAddress`) to know that a given address belongs to a given client. So the first thing to do is to remove `fkIdClientAddress`.

Then the `mappedBy` attribute in `OneToMany` is usd to tell Hibernate which field in address represents the owning `ManyToOne` association. So it must be set to `Client`. (or, if you respect the Java naming conventions and rename the field to `client`, it must be set to `client`).

Finally, having `cascade=ALL` on a `ManyToOne` doesn't make much sense: you don't want to delete the client when you delete one of its addresses. That would fail anyway, since other addresses would still reference the client.

Comment: Thanks i updated the entities as you suggested but when i look into the database the column id_client is still null. Any clues what i could have forgotten ?

Comment: You didn't post the code used to save a client and its addresses, but my guess is that you forgot to set the client field of the addresses. That's required.

Comment: You where right i did forget to set the client. I also added the RequestMapping that saved the client is this the correct way? Or would you do thing different. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Your should set the client in the addresses before saving the client. Saving the addresses is useless, since you have cascade=ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings are wrong. When you define the collection in Client class, you should indicate the field in the AddressClient class which points back to the Client and that is the field `client`.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<AddressClient> addressClientList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in ClientAddress class you have:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_client")
    private Client client;
```

You do not need the field `fkIdClientAddress`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you still can keep column

> @Column
>       private Integer fkIdClientAddress;

But you have to set data for this column instead of setting value for

> private Client client;

But this approach is not appropriate.